# Vertical positioning (stacking) of elements incorrect in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have this simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#message").fadeIn("slow");
</script>

<div id='message' style="display: none;">
    <span>Hey, du har fået +1 points, du har nu <u>2929</u></span>
    <a href="#" class="close-notify" onclick="closeNotice()">X</a>
</div>
```

And i have a design on my site. When i use this, it works and shows it "over" the design, but when i try to view in IE, it shows it "under" the design..

Does it matter where the `<div>` box is? why is it so it shows correct in FF but not IE?

Comment: "FF = correct IE = uncorrect" - I loved this title :-)

Comment: I am surprised that this actually shows up in the first place, display:none should actually hide the contents!

Comment: @questzen: `jQuery.fadeIn()` changes the `display` CSS property to `block` when used.

Comment: @-providerazzzyh: Please use proper tags next time. `js` should be `javascript`, `ie` should be `internet-explorer`, `ff` should be `firefox`. Every few months these shorts tags need to be merged for misuse.

Comment: @-providerazzzy: No problem! You are a new user to the site, it's a common mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the CSS rules applied to `#message`, it is hard to properly answer the question. That being said, I assume you want to create a notification box that resembles the ones on Stack Overflow.

In order to have an element positioned above another, you must assign a `z-index` to the element. `z-index` is a property only evaluated on positioned elements therefore you must also position your `<div>`.

The following CSS should position your `<div>` above all content.

```
#message {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50; /* Anything higher than 1 will do */

  height: 26px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you andrew, and im sorry i didnt apply the css rules for messages.!

Comment: @-providerazzzy: Make sure that `#message` parent container (I assume it's `<body>`) has `width: 100%` and no `padding`.